# Texture is displayed in the wrong order

Tags: java, opengl, libgdx, textures, render

I'm trying to render three cubes with a texture using libgdx but they render incorrectly. Distant textures are drawn first, and then near. Can you help me with the solution?

**Example:**

[image: https://i.imgur.com/RrBaFZi.png]

Here is `Block` class:

```java
public abstract class Block {

    private int x, y, z;

    private ModelInstance model;

    public Block(int x, int y, int z){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;
        OnCreate();
    }

    public abstract void OnCreate();

    public void onDraw(){
        Main.modelBatch.render(model);
    }

    public void setTexture(Texture texture){
        ModelBuilder modelBuilder = new ModelBuilder();
        modelBuilder.begin();

        Material material = new Material(TextureAttribute.createDiffuse(texture));
        int attributes = VertexAttributes.Usage.Position | VertexAttributes.Usage.Normal | VertexAttributes.Usage.TextureCoordinates;

        modelBuilder.part("left", GL20.GL_TRIANGLES, attributes, material).rect(
                createVector(0, 1, -1),
                createVector(0, 0, -1),
                createVector(0, 0, 0),
                createVector(0, 1, 0),
                null
        );
        modelBuilder.part("right", GL20.GL_TRIANGLES, attributes, material).rect(
                createVector(1, 1, 0),
                createVector(1, 0, 0),
                createVector(1, 0, -1),
                createVector(1, 1, -1),
                null
        );
        modelBuilder.part("top", GL20.GL_TRIANGLES, attributes, material).rect(
                createVector(0, 1, -1),
                createVector(0, 1, 0),
                createVector(1, 1, 0),
                createVector(1, 1, -1),
                null
        );
        modelBuilder.part("bottom", GL20.GL_TRIANGLES, attributes, material).rect(
                createVector(0, 0, 0),
                createVector(0, 0, -1),
                createVector(1, 0, -1),
                createVector(1, 0, 0),
                null
        );

        modelBuilder.part("front", GL20.GL_TRIANGLES, attributes, material).rect(
                createVector(0, 1, 0),
                createVector(0, 0, 0),
                createVector(1, 0, 0),
                createVector(1, 1, 0),
                null
        );

        this.model = new ModelInstance(modelBuilder.end());
    }

    private Vector3 createVector(float n1, int n2, int n3){
        return new Vector3(n1 + x, n2 + y, n3 + z);
    }

}
```

Comment: Not sure what's going on exactly.  But it appears to me that you need to [turn on depth testing](https://learnopengl.com/Advanced-OpenGL/Depth-testing).  'Fraid I don't know how to do that in libgdx.

Comment: If you find a solution to your problem, then do not edit the solution into your question, but post it as an answer to your question. I have rolled back your edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Value `camera.near` should be greater than zero (I don't even know how it works)